# IOS - How to draw a border and a shadow that rotates with view but doesn't scale with it

Tags: ios, rotation, scale, shadow

I am developing an ios app.
In my app I have got a view, the view is has got a border and a shadow.
The view can be scaled and rotated.
When a user scaled my view it causes my border and shadow to scale as well.
I don't want my shadow or border to scale at all.
On the other hand I do want my shadow and border to rotate when I rotate the view.

Is there any built in mechanism to prevent border \ shadow scale?

Thank you

Comment: probabily because you didn't offer enough details. I gave you an upvote now to go back to 0, I think your question is legit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't such a built in mechanism.
The only way I see for you to solve your problem is to simply use two different views, with different management in case of rotation.

Have one view as a sort of background and add your border and shadow to it, and then place the content on top of it (or in it, depends on your case).

Comment: yes, but since I am managing my rotation around changing anchor points (based on the original's view scale amongst other things) it will be really though getting it right...

Comment: is there a big chance to change these coordinates? You could consider hardcoding some values instead of reading them from the original view. Or you could even add a third view, as a reference for the coordinates. This is what I ended up doing in a somewhat similar situation. Quite tricky, but it worked

Comment: does it work well though? User can manipulate all objects, I cannot really hard code values, as I am not sure what he'll touch

Comment: Btw Bogdan, how long did it take you to solve this issue? I've been spending the last 25 hours trying to fix it. Trying to measure how long ahead I still have until I can solve my issue

Comment: As I said, my problem was only somewhat similar so I don't think we can compare times. Still, it shouldn't be very difficult, but I might not understand correctly your problem. If the bordered view will contain the content view, the one that should scale, does this mean the scaling will make the content view to be bigger than the one with the border? Also, do you mean a device rotation or an user rotation, made trough code and based on a gesture?

Comment: I mean user rotation, made trough code and based on a gesture

Comment: and will the scaling exceed the borders and the shadow?

Comment: Yes it will most of the times (but not always)

Comment: Yes, than this shouldn't be that hard. You have a view with a shadow and border as a background view. On top of it you can place the view with the actual content. You place the gesture detect on this view and when the user rotates it, you apply the same rotation to the shadow view so this should take care of the rotation problem. The scaling should be simple. If the rotation is based on calculating some anchor points, can't you connect it to a twoFingers rotation gesture, in case you're not already doing it?

Comment: Yes I am using it, I am not trying to convert between the two view's anchor points